# Ratio in which incenter divides median

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, triangle-centres

Apparently, the incentre of a triangle, if it lies on a median, divides it in the ratio $$\frac{BD}{DF} = \frac{AB+BC}{AC} $$ as per this figure(where $BF$ is the median) : [image]

Proving it for isosceles triangles is easy enough (as the incentre lies on the median for all isosceles triangles), but I can't prove it generally. I obtained an equation when I substituted the coordinates of the incentre in the equation for the median, but can't find a way to use it in the distance formulas to prove the above theorem.

Could anyone help point out how to prove it for the general case?

**EDIT:** the equation I got, using coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ for the vertices, is $x_2y_1-x_3y_1-x_1y_2+x_1y_3=x_2y_3-x_3y_2$. (The values of the sides of the triangle, which come with the coordinates of the incentre, vanish by the end.)

Comment: *"I obtained an equation when I substituted the coordinates of the incentre in the equation for the median"* Show this equation. This can save people from duplicating your effort; or, it could help people with identifying an error. (Here, I suspect the latter. I believe the incenter lies on the median *if and only if* the (non-degenerate) triangle is isosceles.)

Comment: In your diagram, if $D$ is the incenter, $\angle ABF = \angle CBF$. You also say $F$ is the midpoint of $AC$. Now try and find a non-degenerate non-isosceles triangle where it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{Note:}$ Here I have used angle bisector theorem for triangles

If incenter lies on median , then that median is one of the angle bisectors of triangle

$\displaystyle\frac{AB}{AF}=\frac{BC}{CF}\implies AB=BC$

as $AF=FC$ as $BF$ is median proving this is possible in case of isosceles triangle only

Make another angle bisector $ADE$ and $CDP$ and then you have

$\displaystyle\frac{AF}{AB}=\frac{FD}{DB}=\frac{CF}{CB}$

Therefore $2\displaystyle\frac{BD}{DF}=\frac{CB+AB}{AF}\implies \frac{BD}{DF}=\frac{CB+AB}{2AF}=\frac{CB+AB}{AC} $